# Filter Logic Help

Tags: filters

Folks,

I can't get the filter logic below to return the desired output. I have a lead (albeit a merged lead) that meets 8 and 9 but isn't being included in the report.

((5 OR 6 OR 8) AND 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 7) OR (8 AND 9)

Here's what I'm after:

1. The first part of the logic is working fine - ((5 OR 6 OR 8) AND 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 AND 7)
2. But I'm trying to add a second part - OR (8 and 9)
3. I want the report to show me leads that match the first part or the leads that match the second part.

Let me know if it's helpful to have screenshots of the filters.

Note: The filter used in 9 is the same as the filter used in 5, but different values are selected. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Screenshot attached. The filters are populated but some of the info is sensitive.

[image]

Comment: the logic seems fine. Show probably screenshots how you setup it and how you know that it doesn't work

Comment: You say you want leads to match both parts, but you're using `OR` to join the two? `OR` means that as long as it satisfies one part, it'll be shown. Did you perhaps mean to join the two with an `AND`?

Comment: Sorry @DerekF — that was a typo. Good spotting. The leads can match either criteria but I want both results returned in the same report.